# CoreData get distinct values of Attribute

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I'm trying to setup my `NSFetchRequest` to core data to retrieve the unique values for a specific attribute in an entity.  i.e.

an entity with the following information:

```
  name | rate | factor |
_______|______|________|
John   |  3.2 |    4   |
Betty  |  5.5 |    7   |
Betty  |  2.1 |    2   |
Betty  |  3.1 |    2   |
Edward |  4.5 |    5   |
John   |  2.3 |    4   |
```

How would i set up the request to return an array with just: John, Betty, Edward?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You should use the backing store to help you get distinct records.

If you want to get an array with just John, Betty, Edward here's how you do it:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MyEntity"];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

// Required! Unless you set the resultType to NSDictionaryResultType, distinct can't work. 
// All objects in the backing store are implicitly distinct, but two dictionaries can be duplicates.
// Since you only want distinct names, only ask for the 'name' property.
fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"name"]];
fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = YES;

// Now it should yield an NSArray of distinct values in dictionaries.
NSArray *dictionaries = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
NSLog (@"names: %@",dictionaries);
```

Comment: AlleyGator, but if I have more than one object with the same attribute (as in the example, more than one Betty), and I don't wanna get repeated values?

Comment: This will give you an array of the three names, with no duplicates. No other data. No rate, no factor.

Comment: I missed the returnsDistinctResults property. Thanks.
Upvoted the answer, but NSArray doesn't have `allValues` method. So I still need to do a for cycle to get each value from each NSDictionary in the array.

Comment: You missed [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

Comment: @glebd fetchRequestWithEntityName: eliminates the need for setEntity:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSFetchRequest/fetchRequestWithEntityName:

Comment: This answer didn't work for me at first. Every time I made a fetch request with the NSDictionaryResultType I got zero results back. The problem was that the context needs to be saved before you'll get the results back, so just save context before making this fetch request.

Comment: @AlleyGator thanx for answer, can you tell a bit more about backing store or just give the links where I can find info about it?

Comment: @StasDerpoliuk Look up NSFetchRequest https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html and the Core Data Framework, Programming Guides. Core Data seems pretty daunting but there's less than 30 classes in the framework. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/CoreData_ObjC/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001181

Answer (score 32):

This is a simple approach in Swift 5.x:

```
// 1. Set the column name you want distinct values for
let column = "name"

// 2. Get the NSManagedObjectContext, for example:
let moc = persistentContainer.viewContext

// 3. Create the request for your entity
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "User")

// 4. Use the only result type allowed for getting distinct values
request.resultType = .dictionaryResultType

// 5. Set that you want distinct results
request.returnsDistinctResults = true

// 6. Set the column you want to fetch
request.propertiesToFetch = [column]

// 7. Execute the request. You'll get an array of dictionaries with the column
// as the name and the distinct value as the value
if let res = try? moc.fetch(request) as? [[String: String]] {
    print("res: \(res)")

    // 8. Extract the distinct values
    let distinctValues = res.compactMap { $0[column] }
}
```

Comment: Getting this crash on the `if let` on step 7: `Fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type`

Comment: @AkashKundu Good catch. The example assumes that the type of the distinct column is `String`. If it's a different type, change `as? [[String: String]]` to `as? [[String: Int]]`, for example. I haven't tested this, but I think that should solve your problem.

Comment: Ah thanks! Actually i was wrong, i realized when creating the request for my entity (step 3), i needed the type to be`NSFetchRequest<NSDictionary>`. That fixed it!

Answer (score 16):

You're trying to use Core Data like a procedural data base instead of as an object graph manager as the API intended, so you won't find an easy way to do this.

There isn't a straight forward way to do this in Core Data because Core Data is concerned with objects instead of values. Since managed objects are guaranteed to be unique, Core Data doesn't much care about each object's values or whether they are duplicates or some other object's values.

To find the unique values:

1. Perform a [fetch by specific value](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW6). That will give you an array of dictionaries with a key `name` and a value of the name string itself.
2. On the returned array in (1) use a [set collection operator](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE) to return a set of unique values.

So, something like:

```
NSSet *uniqueNames=[fetchedNameDicts valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfSets.name"];
```

... which will return a set of NSString objects all with a unique value.

Comment: +1 That's what I was going to say, except that I'd have chosen `@"distinctUnionOfObjects.name"`. I'm not convinced that there's a difference.

Comment: what would the NSExpression and NSExpressionDescription look like for this?

Comment: @ephilip -- I'd open another question on that. I can't squeeze that into a comment.

Comment: Though the answer is correct it's inefficient in terms of processing time and memory usage. I'd take a look at the answer by @AlleyGator.