# fetch list of distinct value from Core Data

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I need to fetch list of distinct value from core data in iOS and this i was to do through predicate i have tried this

```
    [fetchRequest1 setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"b1_CATEGORIA == %@ && b_codpai == %@",@"ABC",@"DISTINCT"]];
```

Here i want to fetch list of all items that have category ABC and are distinct because ABC category may have few items that have same size

So i want to get list of items that are of category ABC and distinct size

Answer (score 1):

If you need a distinct result you may set:

```
fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = YES;
```

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000768/coredata-get-distinct-values-of-attribute).