# Swift 3 - NSFetchRequest Distinct Results

Tags: ios, swift, distinct, nsfetchrequest

Any help appreciated.

Xcode auto updated to 8...  I am Targeting IOS 9.3

Have all of the code converted across but one thing is now breaking, I have tried various suggestions in similar questions! My fetch request that ***was*** previously working is now breaking.

My goal is to get a distinct list.  The app crashes on the line:

```
let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
```

With the error described in the console as:

```
Could not cast value of type 'NSKnownKeysDictionary1' (0x10fd29328) to 'MyApp.BodyType' (0x10eebc820).
```

Here is the function

```
func getBodyTypes() {
            let context = ad.managedObjectContext
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<BodyType>(entityName: "BodyType")
            fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["name"]
            fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = true
            fetchRequest.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.dictionaryResultType

            do {
                let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)

                for r in results {
                    bodyTypes.append(r.value(forKey: "name") as! String)
                }
            } catch let err as NSError {
                print(err.debugDescription)
            }
}
```

If the line below is hidden it doesn't break, but then i don't get what i want!

```
fetchRequest.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.dictionaryResultType
```

I understand i could use all of the results (4300) and loop through them as a bandaid fix, but this doesn't feel like the correct way to fix this, especially as it was working before!

Comment: the same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: Same here :/ Any news? I also temporarily solved it by iterating through the non-distinct results and ignoring duplicates.

Comment: Same issue...i am going to do what @datayeah is doing for time being, but otherwise cannot find any solution to this from SQL side yet.

Comment: My solution below is the fix for this issue. No need to iterate through non-distinct results. Instead, use the general type `NSFetchRequestResult` when setting up your fetch request; then cast the resulting dictionary to the correct data types.

Answer (score 16):

The trick is to make the generic more general - instead of `<BodyType>` in your fetch request, use `<NSFetchRequestResult>`:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "BodyType")
```

The result of this fetch request is `[Any]`, so you will need to cast to the appropriate dictionary type before using. Eg:

```
func getBodyTypes() {
    let context = ad.managedObjectContext
    // 1) use the more general type, NSFetchRequestResult, here:
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "BodyType")
    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["name"]
    fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = true
    fetchRequest.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.dictionaryResultType

    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)

        // 2) cast the results to the expected dictionary type:
        let resultsDict = results as! [[String: String]]

        for r in resultsDict {
            bodyTypes.append(r["name"])
        }

    } catch let err as NSError {
        print(err.debugDescription)
    }
}
```

Note: `NSFetchRequestResult` is a protocol, adopted by four types:
- `NSDictionary`,
- `NSManagedObject`,
- `NSManagedObjectID`, and
- `NSNumber`

Typically, we're using it with an `NSManagedObject`, such as your `BodyType`. In this case, though, you're getting the dictionary type because of the statement:

```
fetchRequest.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.dictionaryResultType
```

Comment: I'm facing the same problem of `.resultDistinctResults`not be taken into account but I'm using a`FetchResultController`to do the fetching, not to do all this setting with results. Could you please have a look at my code an see if you spot what's wrong in there?  this is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56168119/removing-duplicate-objects-from-fetch-based-on-object-parameter-swift 
Thank you very much

Comment: @vincenzo, I looked at your question. It's not actually the same, as it doesn't have to do with casting errors, but rather non-destinct results. I'll taker a deeper dive, still, to see if I can find the issue. I'll answer there, as applicable, since it doesn't apply here...

Comment: thank you very much. just a hint as I'm diving into the problem, I'm turning to use normal fetch and result as dictionary. it actually works as I want as far as I don't use mixed properties type to fetch, as soon as use date as well it returns to be non-distinct results..maybe there's a clue there ..

Comment: I've updated my question with newer code as I found what didn't make the fetch returning distinct results. I wasn't passing `.propertiesToGroupBy` and `.propertiesToFetch` propels. It now works. I just have a one little last issue in using the fetch as data source for my `Tableview`. It'd be great if you could still have a look at it. Thank you very much again.

Comment: I found out what my last problem was. As I was using a `FetchResultsController`to perform the fetch I had to set it's type as dictionary as well. Thank you very for taking interest in my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've outlined a simple step by step approach for Swift 5.x in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60101960/171933