# Distinct value from core data swift

Tags: swift, database, xcode, core-data

i want to get distinct dates from core data.
with this code fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = true is not working.
it is still showing all values.

```
guard let appDelegate =
          UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }
    
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Journal")
    
    
    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["dateAsNumber"]
    fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = true

    do {
    
        dateListSquare = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        
    } catch let error as NSError {
      
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
```

Comment: Give a look for this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60101960/9732124 from Johannes Fahrenkrug

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CoreData get distinct values of Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000768/coredata-get-distinct-values-of-attribute)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want distinct results, you need to set the fetch request's result type to `NSFetchRequestResultType.dictionaryResultType`. You can't fetch managed objects and get distinct results, since there might be more than one managed object with the same value.

That would look something like

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSDictionary> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Journal")
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["dateAsNumber"]
fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = true
fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
```

The result will be an array of dictionaries. Each will have one key per entry in `propertiesToFetch` (just one in this case).

If you use `propertiesToFetch` without `dictionaryResultType`, you affect how faulting works but not the contents of the result. Using `returnsDistinctResults` only works if you also use `propertiesToFetch`, so it's also affected by whether you use `dictionaryResultType`.